# Counter on GPU insanely slow compared to default counter?

Tags: python, cuda, tensorflow

Edit -- see edit at the bottom, tensorflow on gpu is insanely faster for incrementing large vectors of counters.

I'm trying to see if using the GPU is giving me any speed benefit, and this following program that simply counts 200,000 times, once using tensor-flow and the GPU and another time using plain-ol-python. The tensor-flow loop takes over 14 seconds to run while plain ol python takes only .013 seconds? What am I doing wrong? Code below :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tensorflow as tf
import sys, time
# Create a Variable, that will be initialized to the scalar value 0.
state = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")                                                                                            

MAX=10000

# Create an Op to add one to `state`.
one = tf.constant(1)
new_value = tf.add(state, one)
update = tf.assign(state, new_value)

# Variables must be initialized by running an `init` Op after having

# launched the graph.  We first have to add the `init` Op to the graph.
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    # Launch the graph and run the ops.
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Run the 'init' op
        sess.run(init_op)
        # Print the initial value of 'state'
        print sess.run(state)
        # Run the op that updates 'state' and print 'state'.
        print "starting ..."
        t0 = time.time()
        for _ in range(int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else MAX):
            sess.run(update)

        print str(sess.run(state)) + str(time.time() - t0) 

        count = 0 
        print "starting ..."
        t0 = time.time()
        for _ in range(int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else MAX):
            count+=1

        print str(count) + str(time.time() - t0)
```

which outputs this

```
$ ./helloworld.py 200000
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:25] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 8
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:888] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:88] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 970
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.3165
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 4.00GiB
Free memory: 3.69GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:112] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:122] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:643] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_region_allocator.cc:47] Setting region size to 3649540096
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_session.cc:45] Local session inter op parallelism threads: 8
0
starting ...
20000014.444382906
starting ...
2000000.0131969451904
```

EDIT -- after the suggestion to change to vectors of counters, tensorflow on gpu is unbelievably faster.

With 10,000 counters per vector :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tensorflow as tf
import sys, time

CSIZE=10000
# Create a Variable, that will be initialized to the scalar value 0.
state = tf.Variable([0 for x in range(CSIZE)], name="counter")

MAX=1000

# Create an Op to add one to `state`.
one = tf.constant([1 for x in range(CSIZE)])
new_value = tf.add(state, one)
update = tf.assign(state, new_value)

# Variables must be initialized by running an `init` Op after having

# launched the graph.  We first have to add the `init` Op to the graph.
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    # Launch the graph and run the ops.
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Run the 'init' op
        sess.run(init_op)
        # Print the initial value of 'state'
        print sess.run(state)
        # Run the op that updates 'state' and print 'state'.
        print "starting ..."
        t0 = time.time()
        for _ in range(int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else MAX):
            sess.run(update)

        print str(sess.run(state)) + str(time.time() - t0) 

        counters = [0 for x in range(CSIZE)]                                                                                      
        print "starting ..."
        t0 = time.time()
        for _ in range(int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else MAX):
            for x in range(0, len(counters)) :
                counters[x]+=1

        print str(counters[0]) + ", " +  str(time.time() - t0)
```

output :

```
$ ./helloworld.py                                                                                                           127 ↵
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:25] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 8
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:888] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:88] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 970
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.3165
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 4.00GiB
Free memory: 3.69GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:112] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:122] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:643] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_region_allocator.cc:47] Setting region size to 3645083648
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_session.cc:45] Local session inter op parallelism threads: 8
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
starting ...
[10000 10000 10000 ..., 10000 10000 10000]0.997926950455
starting ...
10000, 9.66100215912
```

with 100,000 counters, the output was :

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_region_allocator.cc:47] Setting region size to 3653734400
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_session.cc:45] Local session inter op parallelism threads: 8
[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
starting ...
[10000 10000 10000 ..., 10000 10000 10000]1.57860684395
starting ...
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./helloworld.py", line 40, in <module>
    for x in range(0, len(counters)) :
KeyboardInterrupt
```

the plain ol python took over a minute until I gave up

Comment: GPUs are parallel machines designed for thousands/millions of concurrent operations. You seem to be performing a serial operation. Try incrementing a vector of a million counters.

Comment: Thanks man, this actually worked really well! I made it so I have vectors of 10,000 counters and the results were 1.02350 seconds for tensorflow and 9.7290 for plain ol python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some sense, both programs are "surprisingly" slow, compared to the number of instructions that must be executed. The single-element counter is performing 200,000 increment instructions, using 200,000 calls to `sess.run()`, in 14.4 seconds. The vector counter is performing 100,000,000 increment instructions, using 10,000 calls to `sess.run()`, in 0.99 seconds. If you wrote these programs in C, you would expect to find that each counter increment takes a few nanoseconds at most, so where is the time being spent?

TensorFlow imposes some per-step overhead, on the order of a few microseconds per call to `Session.run()`. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/120), and it is something the team is trying to reduce, but it is rarely a concern for most of the neural network algorithms that one would typically run in a single step. The overhead can be broken down as follows:

- **Per-step dispatch overhead:** The TensorFlow session API is string based, so some string manipulation and hashing has to be done to identify the correct subgraph to run in each step. This involves some Python and some C++ code.
- **Per-op dispatch overhead:** This is implemented in C++, and involves setting up a context and dispatching a TensorFlow kernel. There are three ops in your counter benchmark (`VariableOp`, `Add`, and `Assign`).
- **GPU kernel dispatch overhead:** Dispatching a kernel to the GPU involves a kernel entry to invoke the GPU driver.
- **GPU copy overhead:** Perhaps surprisingly, `sess.run(update)` will copy the result back from the GPU, because `update` is a `Tensor` object (corresponding to the result of the assignment), and its value will be returned from the call.

There are a few things you could try that should speed up both versions of the code.

- Using `state.assign_add(one)` instead of separate `tf.add` and `tf.assign` ops will cut down on the per-op dispatch overhead (and also do a more efficient in-place addition).
- Calling `sess.run(update.op)` will avoid the copy back to the client on each step.